# Comparing and combining arrays of strings from text files

Tags: c#, arrays, parent-child, streamreader

Right off the bat I dont think the wording of the question is accurate, I just dont really know what to write.

That being said, I have 3 txt files that I am loading into this program, Dudes, Tunes, and Bands. Dudes is formatted like this name|instrument, Tunes like this; songName|composer|band|coverArtists1|coverArtists2|etc. And band like this; bandName|bandType|member1|member2|etc. The "|" is where I split the data so each line of the text files become arrays of strings.

What I am trying to do now is when the user inputs the name of a band, it will return the name of the band, its type, and the list each band member and the instrument they play. This process depends on what type of band is inputted. For example a type RockBand needs a guitarist, drummer, bass, and vocalist. Each type of band is its own class that is a subclass of band.

```
    class Program
    {
       static Tunes t1 = new Tunes();
       static Dudes d1 = new Dudes();
       static Bands b1 = new Bands();


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            do
            {

                Console.WriteLine();


            } while (DoAQuery() != "0");

        }

        static string DoAQuery()
        {
            string prompts = "0: Quit \n" +
                             "1: Who wrote <song name> \n" +
                             "2: What does <musician name> play \n" +
                             "3: What songs were written by <composer> \n" +
                             "4: Who plays in the <band name> \n" +
                             "5: Who's recorded <song name> \n" +
                             "6: What songs has the <band name> recorded \n" +
                             "7: Has the <band name> recorded <song name> \n";

            Console.WriteLine(prompts);

            Console.Write("Enter a command number: ");
            string cmd = Console.ReadLine();


            switch (cmd)
            {
                case "0" :
                    return cmd;

                case "1" :
                    Case1();
                    return cmd;

                case "2" :
                    Case2();
                    return cmd;

                case "3":
                    Case3();
                    return cmd;

                case "4":
                    Case4();
                    return cmd;

                case "5":
                    Case5();
                    return cmd;

                case "6":
                    Case6();
                    return cmd;

                case "7":
                    Case7();
                    return cmd;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("!!Command must be a number 0-7!!");
                    return "1";
            }


        }

        static void Case1()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a song name: ");
            string songName = Console.ReadLine();
            t1.Case1(songName);
        }

        static void Case2()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a musician's name: ");
            string musName = Console.ReadLine();
            d1.Case2(musName);
        }

        static void Case3()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a composers name: ");
            string compName = Console.ReadLine();
            t1.Case3(compName);


        }

        static void Case4()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a band name: ");
            string bandName = Console.ReadLine();
            b1.Case4(bandName);

        }
```

Band class

```
class Band
    {
        protected Tunes t1 = new Tunes();
        protected Dudes d1 = new Dudes();

        protected string name;
        protected string type;
        protected List<Tune> recordings = new List<Tune>();

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }

        public List<Tune> Recordings
        {
            get { return recordings; }
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get { return type; }
        }

        public Band(string[] lineAra)
        {
            name = lineAra[0];
            type = lineAra[1];
            //recordings = t1.for4(name);
        }

    }
```

bands class

```
class Bands
    {
        private List<Band> bands = new List<Band>();
        private Dictionary<string, Band> bandsByName = new Dictionary<string, Band>();

        public Bands()
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\bin\Debug\bands.txt";

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader myRdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = myRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] lineAra = line.Split('|');

                        switch(lineAra[1])
                        {

                            case "RockBand":
                                {
                                    RockBand newBand = new RockBand(lineAra);
                                    bands.Add(newBand);
                                    bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "JazzCombo":
                                {
                                    JazzCombo newBand = new JazzCombo(lineAra);
                                    bands.Add(newBand);
                                    bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);
                                    break;
                                }
                            case "SoloAct":
                                {
                                    SoloAct newBand = new SoloAct(lineAra);
                                    bands.Add(newBand);
                                    bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);
                                    break;
                                }
                            default : 
                                {
                                     Band newBand = new Band(lineAra);
                                     bands.Add(newBand);
                                     bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);
                                     break;
                                }

                        }
                        //Band newBand = new Band(lineAra);
                        //bands.Add(newBand);
                        //bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("loaded " + bands.Count + " bands");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading file! Read " + bands.Count + " tunes.");
            }
        }


        public void Case4(string bandName)
        {
            if (bandsByName.ContainsKey(bandName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(bandsByName[bandName].Name + " is a " + bandsByName[bandName].Type);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No band with that name found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

RockBand (subclass of Band)

```
class RockBand : Band
    {


        private Musician vocalist;
        private Musician bass;
        private Musician drums;
        private Musician guitar;


        public RockBand (string[] lineAra) : base (lineAra)
        {

        //I would assign values to four members here

        }
    }
```

Musician Class

```
    class Musician
    {
        string name;
        string instrument;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Instrument
        {
            get { return instrument; }
            set { instrument = value; }
        }

       public Musician(string [] lineAra)
        {
            name = lineAra[0];
            instrument = lineAra[1];
        }
    }
```

Dudes class

```
class Dudes
    {
        static List<Musician> dudes = new List<Musician>();
        Dictionary<string, Musician> dudesByName = new Dictionary<string, Musician>();

        public Dudes()
        {
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\bin\Debug\dudes.txt";

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader myRdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = myRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] lineAra = line.Split('|');
                        Musician newDude = new Musician(lineAra);
                        dudes.Add(newDude);
                        dudesByName.Add(newDude.Name, newDude);

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("loaded " + dudes.Count + " dudes");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading file! Read " + dudes.Count + " tunes.");
            }
        }

        public void Case2(string musName)
        {

            if (dudesByName.ContainsKey(musName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(musName + " plays " + dudesByName[musName].Instrument);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No musician with that name found.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this is a lot of code for what Im pretty sure is a simple problem but I am honestly very confused and dont know where to begin with this part. Thank you in advance, Im happy to provide clarification on anything.

Comment: If you don't know where to begin, you're not ready to ask a good stackoverflow question, I'm afraid. You haven't described your problem clearly, or how far you've gotten.. And yes, it is a lot of code - probably more than you need to demonstrate the problem. There's not even a question-mark in your post. Have you got an actual question?

Comment: I described what I wanted to do, so I didnt really need a question mark. What should I do if I dont know where to begin? I have been trying to get this to work for a relatively absurd amount of time, Im just really stumped

Comment: @LucasKern: You look for guidance. This is probably not the best place to ask for it. However, it sounds like you're challenged by a relational data issue. Have you though about loading the data into internal structures (either custom or out of the box such as DataTables) and go from there?

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason why you want to load the files every time, rather than storing the information in a simple database ?  If you stored the data in a simple database you could quickly and easily return the information with a lower overhead.

You could even use something like entity framework which would provide objects that match the data tables.

Comment: This is a school assignment, so we cant stray too far from what we have learned in class

Comment: @LucasKern Can you assume that the data is correct as in if a band is a rock band the dudes file has the right entries ?  If you can what I would do to answer your question is output the band name, band type.  Then a foreach loop round the songs outputting each one and the same for the musicians.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It's more of a comment. Please use a comment next time.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ben cannot comment on questions until a minimal reputation score of 50 is reached.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst - But that doesn't mean he should write comments as answers.

Comment: @Enigmativity As  said I cant comment so I have no way of providing any assistance or information without using the answer functionality.  Therefore I tried my best to offer a different approach if there is a different approach I'd be happy to take it

Comment: @BenWhyall - I think it does mean that you need to get your reputation up to the point where you can comment. A score of 50 doesn't take very long - it's just 5 upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to give variables and methods meaningful names. Like `tunesRepository` instead of `t1` or `GetMusician` instead of `Case2`.

It seems like you're having trouble understanding how to manage relationships between data. For example, how Band can reference musicians if they're in separate files. A simple solution to this is to give the `Bands` class a reference to the `Musician` class. You can then lookup the musicians by name when creating the band objects:

```
public BandDatabase(MusicianDatabase musicianDatabase)
{
    this.musicianDatabase = musicianDatabase;

    string fileName = @"C:\Code\Sandbox\ConsoleApplication1\input.txt";

    string[] allLines;

    try
    {
        allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading file! Exception: " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    bands = new List<Band>();

    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lineAra = line.Split('|');

            if (lineAra.Length < 2) continue;

            switch (lineAra[1])
            {
                case "RockBand":
                    bands.Add(CreateRockBand(lineAra));
                    break;
                // Rest of cases
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error parsing line {0}. Exception: {1}", line, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    bandsByName = bands.ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);

    Console.WriteLine("loaded " + bands.Count + " bands");
}

private RockBand CreateRockBand(string[] lineAra)
{
    Musician vocalist = null;
    Musician bass = null;
    Musician drums = null;
    Musician guitar = null;

    if (lineAra.Length >= 3) 
        vocalist = musicianDatabase.GetMusicianByName(lineAra[2]);

    if (lineAra.Length >= 4)
        bass = musicianDatabase.GetMusicianByName(lineAra[3]);

    if (lineAra.Length >= 5)
        drums = musicianDatabase.GetMusicianByName(lineAra[4]);

    if (lineAra.Length >= 6)
        guitar = musicianDatabase.GetMusicianByName(lineAra[5]);

    return new RockBand(lineAra, vocalist, bass, drums, guitar);
}
```

You'll need to update the `Band` class a bit for the above constructor to work:

```
public class RockBand : Band
{
    public RockBand(string[] lineAra, Musician vocalist, Musician bass, Musician drums, Musician guitar)
        : base(lineAra)
    {
        Vocalist = vocalist;
        BassPlayer = bass;
        Drummer = drums;
        GuitarPlayer = guitar;
    }

    public Musician Vocalist { get; set; }

    private Musician BassPlayer { get; set; }

    private Musician Drummer { get; set; }

    private Musician GuitarPlayer { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would need to initialize in your `Main` method like so:

```
private static MusicianDatabase musicianDatabase;
private static BandDatabase bandDatabase;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    musicianDatabase = new MusicianDatabase();
    bandDatabase = new BandDatabase(musicianDatabase);
}
```

And you can then print the details when requested:

```
static void PrintBandDetails()
{
    Console.Write("Enter a band name: ");
    string bandName = Console.ReadLine();

    var band = bandDatabase.GetBand(bandName);

    if (band == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid band name")
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Guitarist was " + band.GuitarPlayer);
    // etc.

    var tunes = tuneDatabase.GetByBand(bandName);

    Console.WriteLine("Tunes:");

    foreach(var t in tunes)
        Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

I hope this makes a bit more sense. I've tried to structure everything in terms that you should understand. But if there's still parts that are confusing you let me know.

Comment: @LucasKern I've edited my answer to give more detail. Let me know if there's anything that doesn't make sense.