# Switch statement that makes different child classes of one parent class does not work

Tags: c#, database, switch-statement, streamreader

hopefully this isnt too complicated, I am just wondering why this switch statement isnt working. Band is the parent class and the child classes are different types of bands (RockBand, JazzCombo, SoloAct, default). When I have the switch statement in place it catches and produces the error, only loading 2 bands. Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

```
class Bands
{
    private List<Band> bands = new List<Band>();
    private Dictionary<string, Band> bandsByName = new Dictionary<string, Band>();

    public Bands()
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\bin\Debug\bands.txt";

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader myRdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = myRdr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] lineAra = line.Split('|');

                    switch (lineAra[1])
                    {
                        case "RockBand":
                            Band newBand = new RockBand(lineAra);
                            bands.Add(newBand);
                            bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);
                            break;
                        case "JazzCombo":
                            Band newt = new JazzCombo(lineAra);
                            bands.Add(newt);
                            bandsByName.Add(newt.Name, newt);
                            break;
                        case "SoloAct":
                            Band newB = new SoloAct(lineAra);
                            bands.Add(newB);
                            bandsByName.Add(newB.Name, newB);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Band ddd = new Band(lineAra);
                            bands.Add(ddd);
                            bandsByName.Add(ddd.Name, ddd);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("loaded " + bands.Count + " bands");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading file! Read " + bands.Count + " tunes.");
        }

    }
```

rockband class. This is where my main trouble is, my professor wants us to make the members of the band class Musician but I dont really understand how to utilize it and assign with that class. Ill post that class too.

```
class RockBand : Band
    {


       private Musician vocalist;
       private Musician bass;
       private Musician drums;
       private Musician guitar;


        public RockBand (string[] lineAra) : base (lineAra,)
        {
            vocalist.Name = lineAra[2];




        }
    }
```

Class Musician

```
class Musician
{
    string name;
    string instrument;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Instrument
    {
        get { return instrument; }
        set { instrument = value; }
    }

   public Musician(string [] lineAra)
    {
        name = lineAra[0];
        instrument = lineAra[1];
    }
}
```

The txt file looks like this

```
Al & GenJam|JazzCombo|GenJam|GenJam|GenJam|GenJam|Al Biles
John Coltrane Quartet|JazzCombo|McCoy Tyner|Jimmy Garrison|Elvin Jones|John Coltrane
Beatles|RockBand|John Lennon|Paul McCartney|Ringo Starr|George Harrison
Miles Davis Quintet|JazzCombo|Herbie Hancock|Ron Carter|Tony Williams|Miles Davis|Wayne Shorter
Michael Jackson|SoloAct
Weird Al|SoloAct
Polka Punks|PolkaBand
Herbie Hancock Trio|JazzCombo|Herbie Hancock|Ron Carter|Tony Williams
```

the dudes.txt

```
John Lennon|guitar
Paul McCartney|bass
Ringo Starr|drums
George Harrison|guitar
Al Biles|trumpet
GenJam|code
Michael Jackson|vocals
Weird Al|accordian
John Coltrane|sax
Miles Davis|trumpet
Wayne Shorter|sax
McCoy Tyner|piano
Jimmy Garrison|bass
Elvin Jones|drums
Tony Williams|drums
Herbie Hancock|piano
Ron Carter|bass
```

Also if there is a way to have newBand repeated in each case instead of me different variables for each that would be amazing. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @GrantWinney Thank you for helping! This is the error I get Error reading file! Read 2 tunes.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an obj
ect.
   at KernRadio.RockBand..ctor(String[] lineAra) in c:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documen
ts\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\RockBand.cs:line 21
   at KernRadio.Bands..ctor() in c:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documents\Visual Studio 20
13\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\Bands.cs:line 35

Comment: @LucasKern You have error at the constructor of RockBand. I guess there is an operation where it produce error. Let us know the RockBand code

Comment: @LucasKern Post the `Band` class code - this is where the error is likely coming from. I'm guessing the you're trying to index an element which doesn't exist, i.e, lineAra[2] for the Weird Al entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you were getting the `NullReferenceException` is because you are trying to set the names of musicians before you have initialised the musician objects. What you want to do is this:

```
public class RockBand : Band
{
    private Musician vocalist;
    private Musician bass;
    private Musician drums;
    private Musician guitar;

    public RockBand (string[] lineAra) 
        : base(lineAra)
    {
        if (lineAra.Length >= 3)
            vocalist = new Musician(lineAra[2], "Vocals");

        if (lineAra.Length >= 4)
            bass = new Musician(lineAra[3], "bass");

        if (lineAra.Length >= 5)
            drums = new Musician(lineAra[4], "Drums");

        if (lineAra.Length >= 6)
            guitar = new Musician(lineAra[5], "Guitar");
    }
}
```

You will have to add another constructor to `Musician` for this:

```
public Musician(string name, string instrument)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Instrument = instrument;
}
```

Notice I've also added a check to see if the element exists in the array before trying to access it. This is to avoid an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

You can also simplify the code for loading the file:

```
public Bands()
{
    string fileName = @"C:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\bin\Debug\bands.txt";

    string[] allLines;

    try
    {
        allLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error reading file! Exception: " + ex.Message);
        return;
    }

    bands = new List<Band>();

    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] lineAra = line.Split('|');

            if (lineAra.Length < 2) continue;

            switch (lineAra[1])
            {
                case "RockBand":
                    bands.Add(new RockBand(lineAra));
                    break;
                case "JazzCombo":
                    bands.Add(new JazzCombo(lineAra));
                    break;
                case "SoloAct":
                    bands.Add(new SoloAct(lineAra));
                    break;
                default:
                    bands.Add(new Band(lineAra));
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error parsing line {0}. Exception: {1}", line, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    bandsByName = bands.ToList().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);

    Console.WriteLine("loaded " + bands.Count + " bands");
}
```

Here I've changed the stream reader to just `File.ReadAllLines` and used `.ToDictionary()` to create the lookup after all the bands have been loaded.

I also added error handling for each line so that you will be able to see which line is causing the error if you have problems in future.

If you have any problems understanding changes let me know.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you.  I still dont really know how to fix my overall problem though. What can I do with the musicians I have created in RockBand? There is another class Dudes that functions much the same way as Bands, it reads the dudes.txt and makes a bunch of musician objects. So wouldnt the ones created in RockBand already exist? I dont know....

Comment: @LucasKern I think this seems to be the question you are asking here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134109/comparing-and-combining-arrays-of-strings-from-text-files/29134563#29134563 If you want to accept this answer I will try to clarify in this for you in other question.

Comment: yeah, that would be great. I had kind of given up on that question because of my poor initial wording.

Answer (score -1):

You are using string.Split('|') incorrectly.

You first need to get the entire string, and then call split just once.

```
using (StreamReader myRdr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string entireText;
            if((entireText= myRdr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
            {
                string[] entireTextArray = entireText.Split('|');
                foreach(string band in entireTextArray )
                {
                switch (band)
                {
                    case "RockBand":
                        Band newBand = new RockBand(lineAra);
                        bands.Add(newBand);
                        bandsByName.Add(newBand.Name, newBand);
                        break;
                    case "JazzCombo":
                        Band newt = new JazzCombo(lineAra);
                        bands.Add(newt);
                        bandsByName.Add(newt.Name, newt);
                        break;
                    case "SoloAct":
                        Band newB = new SoloAct(lineAra);
                        bands.Add(newB);
                        bandsByName.Add(newB.Name, newB);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Band ddd = new Band(lineAra);
                        bands.Add(ddd);
                        bandsByName.Add(ddd.Name, ddd);
                        break;
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I use this. Thank you for helping! Error reading file! Read 2 tunes.
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boo
lean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at KernRadio.Bands..ctor() in c:\Users\Lkvideorang\Documents\Visual Studio 20
13\Projects\KernRadio\KernRadio\Bands.cs:line 39

Comment: Dictionary does not allow duplicate Keys.

Comment: Do you know where the duplicate is??

Comment: It seems like you are adding multiple GenJam on the first line.
Al & GenJam|JazzCombo|GenJam|GenJam|GenJam|GenJam|Al Biles

Comment: Oh, thats part of the necessary data though, GenJam is a program my teacher made and it plays several instruments. I really only need to read array[1] because that determines what type it is. I just cant get it to work

Comment: I am not telling you to skip over those, all I am saying is Dictionary does not support duplicate keys. What you need to do is look for alternative data structure that support duplicate keys.

Comment: This isn't correct, @LucasKern doesn't want to loop through every field on every line.